# How to combine two IF statements in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logical-operators

I want to combine the following two IF statements in excel but I was not able to do so. I have tried to use `IF`, `AND`, `OR` statements with no luck.

```
=IF(C98="CAB",D98*R1-F98,F98-D98*S1)
=IF(C99="CAB",I99*R6-D99,F99-I99*S6)
```

Once I want to combine the two I get you are trying to create too many arguments.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: What condition are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please show the formula that you used that gave you the error, we can then help and point you in the right direction.

Comment: You are trying to combine two results of mathematical calculation using boolean operators (`AND`, `OR` etc..). Please add the purpose of the calculation to your question so that we can help.

Comment: Hi Thanks for editing the post. I am new here so please bear with me. I want to calculate something that requires the above formulas, i can achieve the results if I separate the formulas but I wanted to combine them so it is universal. The purpose of the calculation is to calculate Profit and loss, and the main currency i want to use is CAD, and thats applies for two formulas.

Comment: To illustrate further: C represents "CAD" which is the currency, and D is Buy Amount, R is Rate, F is sale amount

Comment: You are checking two things, does C98="Cab", does C99="Cab", so there are 4 possibilities, either the first is TRUE and the second is FALSE, or the first is FALSE and the second is TRUE, or both are FALSE.....or both are TRUE. You need to define what you want the formula to do for all four cases, particularly the latter two

Comment: Okay,The first formula I need it to say this, if currency is CAD then do the calculations, the second formula i need it to say if currency is other than CAD then do this calculation. So should i change "CAD" in the second formula to "OTHERS" so it can read, and how to do so. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine formulas and according to your last comment, it looks like you are trying to do something like this:

```
=if(condition="CAD",perform Calculation,If(Condition="something else",perform calculation,do Nothing or another If statement if needed))
```

You can combine formulas on the True/False part of the if statement.  I don't know if that is exactly what you're trying to do but at least it might get you in the right direction.

Comment: To give also fruther example:
Buy Amount: 150 / Sale Amount: 2000 / First Currency: CAD / Second Currency: USD
FirstRate = 3.7510 / SecondRate = 3.7490
If I use the first formula, I would need to use the following:
=IF(C2=”CAD”,buyAmount * firstRate-saleAmount,saleAmount-buyAmount * secondRate)
That’s if I am sure the currency in the buy side is CAD, and if its USD/CAD then it will calculate using 
saleAmount-buyAmount * secondRate which is the second part of the first formula. 

The second formula is totally other currencies against CAD, for example CAD/PKR, CAD/INR etc.

Comment: Hi R.Rpe, I tried using Nested IF, but I get the following error. You've entered too many arguments for this function.

Comment: It has to be in the format  `if(condition,True,False)` you can't have any more if you want to nest if statements it still has to follow those rules. `if(condition,true,if(condition,True,False))` the second condition fills the `False` part of the first condition. This can go on and on, and you can substitute the `True` part of the condition with another if statement too.