# I keep getting "you've entered too many arguments for this function" Why"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, arguments

I keep getting

> You've entered too many arguments for this function

Why?

```
=IF(
  Home!O17=6,
  Home!H17,
  0,
  IF(
    Home!O17=2,
    Home!H20,
    0,
    IF(
      Home!O17=3,
      Home!H23,
      0,
      IF(
        Home!O17=4,
        Home!H26,
        0,
        IF(
          Home!O17=5,
          Home!H29,
          0
        )
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: `=IF(Home!O17=6,Home!H17,0,IF`... that's four arguments - you don't want the `0` there, and similarly elsewhere.

Comment: You could use `CHOOSE` here.

Comment: for nested if statements see post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443128/how-to-combine-two-if-statements-in-excel/48444321#48444321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're passing four arguments into a three argument function. In Excel, the function call is:

```
=IF (logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

Based on the structure, I am guessing you want to remove every "0," to get down to three args. Something like so:

```
=IF(Home!O17=6,Home!H17,IF(Home!O17=2,Home!H20,IF(Home!O17=3,Home!H23,IF(Home!O17=4,Home!H26,IF(Home!O17=5,Home!H29,0))))
```

That said, I have no idea what this should accomplish and I'm just guessing that you wanted to daisy chain this. Maybe it's actually supposed to be entirely separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

> =IF(Home!O17=6,Home!H17,IF(Home!O17=2,Home!H20,IF(Home!O17=3,Home!H23,IF(Home!O17=4,Home!H26,IF(Home!O17=5,Home!H29,0)))))